# Dynamic groupingBy keyselector in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I would like to pass a dynamic `keySelector` to my `groupingBy` function. Is this possible?

```
   private fun hasNumberOfIdenticalValues(hand: ArrayList<Card>, values: ArrayList<String>, limit: Int) : Boolean {
        var numberOfOccurrences : Map<String, Int> = hashMapOf()

        for(value in values) {
            numberOfOccurrences = hand.groupingBy{it.suit}.eachCount()
        }

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, you just need to return the string that will classify the interation. For instance, to separete the cards by color of the suit:

```
fun Card.color(): String {     
    return if(listof("diamonds","hearts").contains(this.suit)) 
        "red" 
    else 
        "black" 
}

for(value in values) {
    numberOfOccurrences = hand.groupingBy{it.color()}.eachCount()
}
```